# How to escape curly bracket in AWS CLI Bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to use AWS CLI Lambda to replace environment variables. However the value I want to replace has a pair of curly braces in it and CLI complaints about json format even when I already put the whole thing in single quote. Here's my command:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name myFunc --environment Variables={URL='http://example.com/api/{0}'}
```

Here's the error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--environment': Expected: ',', received: '}' for input:
```

The funny thing is that if I removed the closing bracket `}`, it worked:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name myFunc --environment Variables={URL='http://example.com/api/{0'}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: The shell is removing the single quotes, as if you had used `Variables={URL=http://example.com/api/{0}}`. I'm not familiar enough with AWS to know exactly why the missing single quotes would cause that particular error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose in double quotes:

```
Variables="{URL='http://example.com/api/{0}'}"

aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name myFunc --environment Variables="{URL='http://example.com/api/{0}'}"
```

> An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the
>   UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: Function not found:
>   arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:1234567890:function:myFunc

Answer (score 2):

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name myFunc --environment "Variables={URL='http://example.com/api/{0}'}"
```

Here is the detailed issue regarding double  quotes in aws cli
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2638

Answer (score 0):

This worked, my command is different though.

```
aws apigateway update-resource \
    --rest-api-id <rest_api_id> \
    --resource-id <resource_id> \
    --patch-operations 'op=replace,path=/pathPart,value="{something}"'
```

The points are:

- Single quote to for the whole argument,
- Double quote to for the outer curly bracket.